# Some images are getting loaded some not, using Spring - Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I am trying to migrate a project of mine from pure HTML/CSS/Javascript to a Spring MVC application with Thymeleaf.
I am not understanding why my Thymeleaf template is loading some images and some not.
I have checked the syntax and I don't believe that's the problem.
All images are stored in the same folder.

```
resources
|
|-------- static
           |
           |---- images
                       |---- image1
                       |---- image2
                       |---- and so on
```

The syntax I am using to refer to those images is:

```
<img th:src="@{/images/image1.jpg}" />
```

And also:

```
<div th:style="'background:url(' + @{/images/image2.jpg} + ');'"
```

It's a couple of days I am dealing with this issue and the weirdest part is that a few images have just fixed, no idea how, no change from me. I wonder if other tiny bugs, like wrong html syntax elsewhere, may be causing the problem.

Any ideas?

Thank you for your time and experience.

Comment: A good place to start is: can you see the images if you visit its absolute path in the browser? https://example.com/images/image1.jpg (and image2, ...)

Comment: Nice one. Yes i do see the images properly. Also intelliJ sees them if I do CTRL + click where the images are used.
I really don't know what it could be causing the issue.

Chrome console says: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Comment: By any chance, is the project hosted somewhere so that I can visit it? If not, since you're working with background: are some divs empty? Try adding a fixed height and width to it, just to see if the images appear. Because if the div is empty, then the background image will not be shown unless there is a fixed height and width

Comment: No sorry, it is a local project.
I will check my code for your suggestion, though I don't believe that's the case because before doing the migration to Spring and Thymeleaf the images were showing just fine on my webpage

Comment: I checked by adding a min dimension to the images but nothing changed

Comment: So after experimenting by taking the tag of one image that wasn't displaying and pasting it starting from the <body> and moving down untill where that image is actually used... now that image shows up. I am totally confused. Could it be a problem of cache or something like such?

Comment: That seems highly unlikely. And this solves it for every image that didn't work before?